# How to use update output mode with FileFormat format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use spark structured streaming in update output mode write to a file. I found [this StructuredSessionization example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredSessionization.scala) and it works fine as long as the console format is configured. But if I change the output mode to:

```
 val query = sessionUpdates
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("update")
  .format("json")
  .option("path", "/work/output/data")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/work/output/checkpoint")
  .start()
```

I get following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Data source json does not support Update output mode;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:286)
        at palyground.StructuredStreamingMergeSpans$.main(StructuredStreamingMergeSpans.scala:84)
        at palyground.StructuredStreamingMergeSpans.main(StructuredStreamingMergeSpans.scala)
```

Can i use update mode and use the FileFormat to write the result table to a file sink? 
In the source code i found a pattern match that ensures Append Mode.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot write to file in update mode using spark structured streaming. You need to write `ForeachWriter` for it. I have written simple for each writer here. You can modify it according to your requirement.

```
val writerForText = new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    var fileWriter: FileWriter = _

    override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
      fileWriter.append(value.toSeq.mkString(","))
    }

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
      fileWriter.close()
    }

    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File(s"src/test/resources/${partitionId}"))
      fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(s"src/test/resources/${partitionId}/temp"))
      true

    }
  }

val query = sessionUpdates
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("update")
  .foreach(writerForText)
  .start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I just had to change the ForeachWriter[Row] to ForeachWriter[SessionUpdate].

Answer (score 1):

`Append` output mode is required for any of the `FileFormat` sinks, incl. `json`, which Spark Structured Streaming [validates before starting your streaming query](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala#L286-L293).

```
if (outputMode != OutputMode.Append) {
  throw new AnalysisException(
    s"Data source $className does not support $outputMode output mode")
}
```

In Spark 2.4, you could use `DataStreamWriter.foreach` operator or the brand new `DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch` operator that simply accepts a function that accepts the Dataset of a batch and the batch ID.

```
foreachBatch(function: (Dataset[T], Long) => Unit): DataStreamWriter[T]
```