# Does Watermark in Update output mode clean the stored state in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on a spark streaming application and while understanding about the sinks and watermarking logic, I couldn't find a clear answer as to if I use a watermark with say 10 min threshold while outputting the aggregations with update output mode, will the intermittent state maintained by spark be cleared off after the 10 min threshold has expired?

Comment: Updated answer. As indeed one aspect not clear in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

**Watermark** allows late arriving data to be considered for inclusion against already computed results for a period of time using windows. Its premise is that it tracks back to a point in time (threshold) before which it is assumed no more late events are supposed to arrive, but if they do, they are discarded.

As a consequence one needs to maintain the state of window / aggregate already computed to handle these potential late updates based on event time. However, this costs resources, and if done infinitely, this would blow up a Structured Streaming App.

**Will the intermittent state maintained by spark be cleared off after the 10 min threshold has expired?** Yes, it will. There is by design as there is no point holding any longer a state that can no longer be updated due to the threshold having been expired.

You need to run through some simple examples as I note it is easy to forget the subtlety of output.

> See
>   [Why does streaming query with update output mode print out all rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552865/why-does-streaming-query-with-update-output-mode-print-out-all-rows)
>   which gives an excellent example of update mode output as well. Also this gives an even better update example: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/28/structured-streaming-in-apache-spark.html
>
> Even better - this blog with some good graphics: https://towardsdatascience.com/watermarking-in-spark-structured-streaming-9e164f373e9

Comment: The official documentation : [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes) says in update mode watermark will be used to drop the old aggregation state. My doubt is even if i don't use window for aggregation, the old state in StateStoreSaveExec will be dropped or not? The intention is not to collect too much data of intermittent aggregation state causing OOM.

Comment: Didn't get the response, how can I not waste too much disk to store the intermittent aggregation state when it is guaranteed that there will no more updates in the aggregation apart from the current micro-batch. My other question might give you more context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705311/can-i-say-only-current-batch-by-watermarking-and-window-logic-for-aggregating-a