# spark structured streaming parquet overwrite

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

i would like to be able to overwrite my output path with parquet format, 
but it's not among available actions (append, complete, update), 
Is there another solution here ?

```
val streamDF = sparkSession.readStream.schema(schema).option("header","true").parquet(rawData)

val query = streamDF.writeStream.outputMode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("checkpointLocation",checkpoint).start(target)
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I never understand writing to parquet for microbatches, is it not too slow?

Comment: @thebluephantom ,it's not bad, but do you have some advice ?

Comment: It's columnar, normall for thruput that will be slower to build parquet, at least that is what I learnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Spark only support `Append` mode for `File Sink`. [Check out here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes)

You need to write code to delete path/folder/files from `file system` before writing a data.

[Check out this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026429/how-to-use-update-output-mode-with-fileformat-format) for `ForeachWriter`. This will help you to achieve your case.